# Firebase Admin SDK causes gradle "Dependency Error"

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, firebase-admin

I'm trying to add the Firebase Admin SDK to my project. When I add this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.1'
```

It gives me a  "Dependency Error" When I sync.

The stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Dependency Error. See console for details.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PrepareDependenciesTask.prepare(PrepareDependenciesTask.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the Firebase Admin SDK inside an Android app.  You have to write a different Java program for that, which normally resides on a server you control.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097740/firebase-admin-sdk-for-android-methods-not-found/) for other problems that can come up if you try to use firebase-admin from within an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

do u have server project or android? [Firebase Admin SDK Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_the_sdk)
it says "Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your Server"

check out this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097740/firebase-admin-sdk-for-android-methods-not-found)

Comment: I have an Android project. And I'm not willing to buy a server for this reason. All I want is custom authentication. It's a pitty Google makes it this complicated.

Comment: why don't you just use custom auth of Firebase API?
This tutorial explained how to add custom auth to your apps https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=66902019&postcount=5  also you can check firebase doc itself

Comment: All these are trying to make me use the admin sdk

Comment: I don't want neither email nor password. I just want phone number. Sort of like whatsapp

Comment: i recommend this Fabric guide https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html good luck