# Fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing an Android app using Firebase, and went to install the Admin SDK using this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). In my `build.gradle` file in my app, I've had a couple of dependencies that have given me warnings since I added them earlier in the project, but I was still able to run the application. Once I added the dependency needed for Admin SDK, things got a little more serious...

These are the original dependencies and their warnings:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'`

> All gms/firebase libraries must be the exact same version specification. Found versions 9.6.0, 11.8.0

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

> All com.android.support libraries must be the exact same version specification. Found versions 26.1.0, 23.4.0

I searched the whole project using the double-shift search function in Android Studio and couldn't find anything that used either of the conflicting versions mentioned (9.6.0 or 23.4.0).

Like I said, the app still ran so I carried on developing. While adding the Firebase Admin SDK, I added the following dependency to my `build.gradle`:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.6.0'`

When I hit 'sync' on my gradle, I got the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.

This has left me a bit confused as I believe the most recent version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin` to be 5.6.0, so I don't see how I can be getting a version conflict for using this.

My app won't run while this error exists, so any help getting past it would be very much appreciated. I'm new to Android development so it might well be something very obvious that I've missed.

Here is my full list of dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' <-- warning
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0' <-- warning
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.6.0' <-- introduced error
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}
```

If I can include anything else that will help with diagnosing, please let me know!

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase admin SDK is meant for JVM servers and can't be used in tandem with client SDKs. See this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103063/4548500) for more details. I would recommend using [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) for admin stuff instead since they're something you control and can't be compromised on the client.