# How to solve Firebase Admin SDK dependencies incompatibility?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

I'm trying to add

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.9.0'
```

But they seem to be incompatible. What versions should I use? I went through the Firebase documentation but I can't seem to find any answers there.

Comment: Try: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.10.0' and 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'

Comment: Use of the admin SDK is not supported in mobile applications.  It's for use on backend servers only.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me ask you, why do you need firebase-admin? What are you trying to acomplish?

**You should not add firebase-admin to your android app**, as this lib is meant to be used only on trusted sources (that is, on code that runs securely behind a server). If you added firebase-admin to your app, you would be giving admin privileges for any user using the app, and this would be a security liability for your application.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103063/6605392) for more information.

Comment: Oh. Well I'm trying to get a functionality where I can delete certain users. I know I can delete the currently authenticated user but I need to do more than that. I want a user that will have Administrator Privileges and be able to manage the rest of them. As I understood from the documentation, I can only delete other users if I user firebase-admin

Comment: @OctavianCatusanu So you will add an administrator type view in the app for you to manage users/data?

Comment: @OctavianCatusanu, I see... Maybe the path to solve your requirement would be to implement a firebase cloud function that would handle user deletion, and making sure that this function will only run for a user with admin privileges (maybe you will also need to add a flag isAdmin to the user node in DB). This way the admin code would be secure to run on server/cloud side

Comment: Also, you could work with a "logical delete" instead of a real delete. For example, just use the app code to add a flag to the user nodes you meant to delete (e.g: isDisabled: true), stating that they are no longer active. Then in your app you make sure you only fetch users with isDisabled: false. For this type of edit you don't need admin rights.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll try to write a workaround based on them!

Comment: @Michael, I have an administrator type view in my app where I can create the users. I just need to delete them