# Build Fail with 'com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-admin

Hello when i implementing

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.0'

I am getting the error like

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp

I have tried the below steps

- Clear Project
- Invalid catch and restart
- Rebuild

But still getting same error. I i removed **com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.0** then i work well without it.

**Here my app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sccpl.smartrestaurant"
        minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
        targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
        versionCode build_versions.version_code
        versionName build_versions.version_name

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
       }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}


dependencies {
//    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Support libraries
    implementation deps.support.app_compat
    implementation deps.support.v4
    implementation deps.support.design
    implementation deps.support.cardview
    implementation deps.support.recyclerview
    //constraint layout
    implementation deps.constraint_layout
    implementation deps.glide.runtime
    implementation deps.staggeredtextgridview
    // Gson
    implementation deps.gson
    // dragger
    implementation deps.dagger.runtime
    implementation deps.dagger.android
    implementation deps.dagger.android_support
    annotationProcessor deps.dagger.compiler
    annotationProcessor deps.dagger.android_support_compiler
    // retrofit2
    implementation deps.retrofit.runtime
    implementation deps.retrofit.gson
    //    implementation deps.retrofit.rxjava
    //    implementation deps.retrofit.mock
    implementation deps.okhttp_logging_interceptor
    androidTestImplementation deps.atsl.runner
    androidTestImplementation deps.atsl.rules
    androidTestImplementation deps.room.testing
    androidTestImplementation deps.arch_core.testing
    // Espresso UI Testing
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.core
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.contrib
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.intents
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0-RC1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.0'

//    implementation 'com.github.shchurov:horizontalwheelview:0.9.5'
    implementation project(':SerialPortApi')
    implementation project(':library')
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My root project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    addRepos(repositories)

    dependencies {
        classpath deps.android_gradle_plugin
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}

allprojects {
    addRepos(repositories)
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Build and Support versions which i am using**

```
build_versions.min_sdk = 21
build_versions.target_sdk = 28
build_versions.build_tools = "28.0.3"
versions.support = "28.0.0"
```

I have tried using **multidix** and also referred more links but still didnt get any solutions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592409/6478047

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase Admin SDK isn't supported for use in Android apps. It's intended for use in server applications.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097740/firebase-admin-sdk-for-android-methods-not-found.