# where i can write or edit the firebase admin sdk code in my android project?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-admin

I am new in android development and I have an android project in android studio that use firebase and I am following the documentation of admin sdk "**Add the Firebase Admin SDK to Your Server**" to control the roles of users in my android application, but really I don't understand the documentation,
my question is where i can write or edit the firebase admin sdk code (that illustrated below) in my android project ?

here is the snippet code from the tutorial

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

*Firebase Admin SDK is supposed to be installed and used on a **Server-side** and not on Client side (Android app).* You can't use it even if you want to.

(Read - [Firebase Admin SDK for Android, methods not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097740/firebase-admin-sdk-for-android-methods-not-found))

So you have to install the Admin SDK on a Server and write your logic there and make requests to the server from your Android app to get the results you want.

Hope it helps